# How to force QtQuick Column to relayout? .forceLayout() doesn't work

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a `Column` with many items which are toggled via `Loader.active`.

Simplified scenario:

```
Column {
    id: column
    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100; color: "white"
        Column {
            CheckBox { id: chkRed; text: "Red"; checked: true }
            CheckBox { id: chkGreen; text: "Green"; checked: true }
            CheckBox { id: chkBlue; text: "Blue"; checked: true }
        }
    }
    Loader {
        active: chkRed.checked
        onActiveChanged: column.forceLayout()
        sourceComponent: Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 100; color: "red"
        }
    }
    Loader {
        active: chkGreen.checked
        onActiveChanged: column.forceLayout()
        sourceComponent: Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 100; color: "green"
        }
    }
    Loader {
        active: chkBlue.checked
        onActiveChanged: column.forceLayout()
        sourceComponent: Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 100; color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the item is removed (via setting `Loader.active = false`), it remains a "hole" of the space previously occupied by the item, i.e. the other items are not repositioned.

I tried to add `onActiveChanged:`[`column.forceLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html#forceLayout-method) to every `Loader` but it has no effect.

[image]

Comment: `Loader` inherits from `Item` and has its own size. When you deactivate a Loader the content item releases but the Loader itself still persists. You can use `visible` instead of `active`

Comment: Makes sense. Adding `visible: active` to each `Loader` solves the issue.